# Need to learn wavelet, suggest steps and resources

Tags: reference-request, fourier-analysis, signal-processing, online-resources, wavelets

I am looking for a good introduction to wavelets and wavelet transforms.

that covers the following:

**Basics**

- Vector Spaces – Properties– Dot Product – Basis – Dimension, Orthogonality and Orthonormality
- Relationship Between Vectors and Signals – Signal Spaces
- Concept of Convergence
- Hilbert Spaces for Energy Signals
- Fourier Theory: Fourier series expansion, Fourier transform, Short time Fourier transform, Time-frequency analysis.

**Multi-resolution analysis**

- Definition of Multi Resolution Analysis (MRA)
- Haar Basis
- Construction of General Orthonormal MRA
- Wavelet Basis for MRA
- Continuous Time MRA Interpretation for the DTWT
- Discrete Time MRA
- Basis Functions for the DTWT
- PRQMF Filter Bank

**Continuous wavelet transforms**

- Wavelet Transform – Definition and Properties – Concept of Scale and its Relation with Frequency
- Continuous Wavelet Transform (CWT)
- Scaling Function and Wavelet Functions (Daubechies-Coiflet, Mexican Hat, Sinc, Gaussian, Bi Orthogonal)
- Tiling of Time – Scale Plane for CWT

**Discrete wavelet transform**

- Filter Bank and Sub Band Coding Principles
- Wavelet Filters
- Inverse DWT Computation by Filter Banks
- Basic Properties of Filter Coefficients; Choice of Wavelet Function Coefficients
- Derivations of Daubechies Wavelets
- Mallat's Algorithm for DWT
- Multi Band Wavelet Transforms Lifting Scheme
- Wavelet Transform Using Polyphase Matrix Factorization
- Geometrical Foundations of Lifting Scheme
- Lifting Scheme in Z –Domain.

**Applications**

- Wavelet methods for signal processing
- Image Procession: Compression Techniques: EZW–SPHIT Coding; Denoising Techniques: Noise Estimation – Shrinkage Rules – Shrinkage Functions –
  Edge Detection and Object Isolation, Image Fusion, and Object Detection.

Please suggest the steps,resources and materials to do the same. And the time frame to master in this.

Comment: Your detailed list of "covered material" has relatively little to do with wavelets per se. The first third of your list is covered in any linear algebra textbook/course; the middle third seems to be about signal processing; and the last third is applied Fourier theory. I would say the list you gave are more like _prerequisites_ for starting to study wavelets.

Comment: yes this is the first intro part i'll add the rest of the part now thanks @WillieWong

Comment: My suggestion is to stay away from Mallat. I found that book to be horribly written with very awkward and unnecessarily complicated notation.

Answer (score 3):

In that case, I recommend "*A Friendly Guide to Wavelets*" by *Gerald Kaiser*. It includes a clear introduction to linear algebra, some fundamentals of Fourier Analysis and Windowed Fourier Transform, and a presentation of wavelets for those who had not heard of that.

Answer (score 1):

How about learning the subject from [Wavelets and Filter Banks, by Gilbert Strang and Truong Nguyen](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0961408871). The legendary MIT Professor has a great knack of explaining stuff.